# moodle data root location not secure error

Tags: .htaccess, moodle

I read moodles documentation where it says that if the data root directory has to be in the site's public html folder ( Please see that i can not create it outside it since i dont have sufficient privileges as i am using a free account ). then you have to chmod it to 770 and also use htaccess to protect it. 
Now i am creating the moodle inside my domain at folder /moodle/
and moodle uploads folder is /moodle-uploads/uploads/
and i have an .htaccess setup in /moodle-uploads/.htaccess
where its contents are

```
order deny,allow
deny from all
```

as specified on 
http://docs.moodle.org/20/en/Creating_Moodle_site_data_directory

But still when i run the auto installer script it says the data root directory is not secure

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**This is not the best way of doing it** but coding hack to just get rid of this error if you like try it..,

in moodle root go the install.php and if you are using 2.6 in line 341 or others versions search for `is_dataroot_insecure()` function and change it to false in the else if condition and try to install again,and that it..,

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. Solves my problem

Answer (score 3):

By default its going to give you warning for having it in the public html folder as according to the docs in the link you also provided.

> Remember that by default moodle will issue a warning about moodle data
>   directories created inside the web directory, but otherwise this
>   directory can be located where you wish. You can later move or change
>   the location of this directory, but if you do, be sure to edit the
>   setting in the config.php file that sets this; e.g. if moodledata is
>   under a directory called data, then it would look like this:

As long as you have configured the dataroot location with the moodle data directory and placed your .htaccess file in that folder it should be fine.

Comment: I cant seem to understand what you said, are you saying that once I have to create it outside doc root and then I can have it inside document root If I wish. Coz now even with htaccess I am not able to install in document root